# How can ContainsKey(string key) throw a KeyNotFoundException on a Dictionary<string, string>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

How it is possible that you get a `KeyNotFoundException` when calling a Dictionary?

Given the signature of the method I'm calling:

```
IDictionary<string, string> RequestParams { get; }
```

Given the call that I'm making:

[image]

Given that I am returning a `Dictionary<string, string>` as follows:

```
    public IDictionary<string, string> RequestParams
    {
        get
        {

            NameValueCollection nvc = HttpContext.Request.Params;

            #region Collect the Request Params
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            nvc.AllKeys.ForEach(s => dict[s] = nvc[s]);
            #endregion

            #region Collect the Route Data Present in the Url
            RouteData.Values.ForEach(pair =>
            {
                string param = (pair.Value ?? "").ToString();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param) && Uri.AbsolutePath.Contains(param))
                    dict[pair.Key] = param;
            });
            #endregion

            return dict;
        }
    }
```

And I've actually inspected that it indeed returns an instantiated and populated `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: What type of class is `RequestParams` when you get the exception? Also, you should edit your question to say "Given that I am returning an `IDictionary<string, string>`"

Comment: @mason I've added the method implementation. Managed code.

Comment: `ContainsKey` isn't throwing the exception, your property getter is. And that is why you never put surprising code like this in property getters. Constructing a new object every time it's called is unexpected, especially if constructing it can *fail* -- getters should not throw exceptions.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Please elaborate with some code examples. I want to hear more from you.

Comment: @mason it's the Dictionary<string, string>.ContainsKey(). I have not overriden it.

Comment: "And I've actually inspected that it indeed returns an instantiated and populated `Dictionary<string, string>`" -- prove it. Change your method to `var requestParams = Context.RequestParams; return requestParams.ContainsKey("languageCode")` and see where this fails (with, per @MichaelLiu, a stack trace).

Comment: The code for Dictionary is here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs I can't see it throwing that exception.

Comment: @JaniHyytiäinen Again, please **post the stack trace**. You haven't overridden `ContainsKey()` but your exception isn't coming from there. You're not even reaching the `ContainsKey()` part of that line, you're stuck in the getter for `RequestParams`.

Comment: @mason I will. As soon as I recover from this `Update-Package -reinstall` I threw in frustration only to generate more of it :)

Answer (score 7):

Notice, not `Dictionary`, but `IDictionary`. The underlying implementation can do whatever it wants to do, even shut down your computer.

The `Dictionary` does not throw any exceptions (except key null exception) when using `ContainsKey`.

It's possible that the specific implementation of `IDictionary` you're using, throws `KeyNotFoundException`, but that would still be weird - although, I've seen a lot weirder things, so don't panic :-)!

Possible causes:

- Your getter is throwing exceptions through another getters - use StackTrace to find out the origin.
- You are using wrong `Dictionary`, make sure you have namespace `System.Collections.Generic`
- You might be running old code - this has happened to me, very painful. Even the debugging symbols might work. Just do some modifications: comment out something obvious, and see if it has any impact. If you comment out line 64 and you get KeyNotFoundException, you know something is... not good ^_^

Comment: Even null key behavior cannot necessarily be relied on according to the documentation `"Implementations can vary in whether they allow key to be null."`

Comment: @JeffWard Are you confusing `IDictionary` with `Dictionary`? Chris was talking about `Dictionary`'s implementation of `ContainsKey`

Comment: @mason: I am expecting the "ahh it wasn't the latest code I was running" or something similiar - as far as the getter goes, there's nothing wrong with that either. `NameValueCollection` does not throw `KeyNotFoundException` at all, and dictionary indexer is never used in expression. Perhaps secondary getter :-)?

Answer (score 1):

It can't throw that exception.

look at the using statements of the file with the getter. do you see:

```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
```

or is it:

```
  using MyAmazingLib.BetterThanMS.Collections;
```